# Trying to get dual monitors working 14.04 LTS & Radeon HD 4850

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, radeon, fglrx, amd-graphics

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on a desktop PC and recently got a second monitor. I cannot seem to make Ubuntu 'detect' that second one.

I ended up [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver), and realised that my HD 4850 needs that driver, and that it ships with Ubuntu by default. That may be the case, but it doesn't do what I would expect.

I tried installing `fglrx` and the solutions offered [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx), but nothing seems to work. The second display just won't show up in system settings :(

I am not a Linux-newbie, but I never encountered problems with graphic drivers before.

**Update 15 Mar 16**

[This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) tells me the 'open source Radeon driver' supports my card (the RV770 chipset on my Radeon HD4850) and that it should be enabled by default in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I tried the commmands under 'Testing the driver' and they output no errors in the log file and a bunch of code like this (for the command `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo`)

```
0x06e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
```

But still the second monitor DOES NOT show up in system settings. Where am I going wrong?